# JSF AJAX show form once form submits

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to show another form if the result that returns from the first form is 'Correct'. However, so far nothing shows.

This is my code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Results Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{jsfbean.message}"/>
    <h:form>
        <p>Answer the question to change your password</p>
        <h:outputText value="#{jsfbean.secqn}"/>

        <h:inputText id="question" value="#{jsfbean.inpans}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit">
            <f:ajax execute="question" render="output" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <h:outputText id="output" value="#{jsfbean.inpans}" />
    <h:form rendered="#{jsfbean.inpans eq 'Correct'}">
        <h:inputText id="reset" value="#{jsfbean.inpans}"/>
    </h:form>


</h:body>
```

Comment: You put rendered="#{jsfbean.inpans eq 'Correct'}" on inputText  and update the 2nd form. Between why do you need 2 forms?

Comment: I want to reveal a follow up form if the first is correct. I don't really understand. Why would I put it in the input text and if I did, how do I reveal the form?

Comment: That one uses a selectmenu? thing? I'm trying to use a commandbutton

Comment: Have you able to solve your issue?

Comment: Not at the moment. I can't seem to get p:ajax to work. Only f:ajax works

Comment: But in your question you have used <f:ajax/>. More over it works with <p:ajax/> also.

Comment: nah..i can't put update in f:ajax

Comment: You use render in f:ajax and update in p:ajax

Comment: I can't use p:ajax still as they ask me to add a passthrough import and then say that the component library Passthrough does not contain ajax